# PatternLayout < > escape character in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to output a pattern that contains the characters < > in the form

08:06:41 DEBUG 69 [ch.fhnw.edu.rental.model.Movie] - <Movie 'Cars' created>

Where <Movie 'Cars' created>  is the log-message.

My PatternLayout is as follows:

```
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %L [%c] - <%m%n>"/>
```

Unfortunately this produces the error

> [Fatal Error] log4j2.xml:5:65: The value of attribute "pattern" associated with an element type "PatternLayout" must not contain the '<' character.

How can I escape the < > characters without hardcoding them into the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) codes for this: `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`.

Be careful where you place them:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %L [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n"/>
```

In the above example, the `&gt;` needs to be placed before the `%n` since `%n` generates a newline.